# Delphi - get user EmailAddress from active directory

Tags: delphi, active-directory

I'm trying to get the e-mail address of a user by using `sAMAccountName` from Active Directory but I'm getting this error message:

> The directory property cannot be found in the cache.

I can get fullname, department and discretion, but why am I getting this error for e-mail ?

```
uses
  ActiveDs_TLB, adshlp;

procedure TMainForm.btnFillInfoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Usr: IAdsUser;
  lStr: HRESULT;
  xStrg: string;
  ChkPRN: string;
  RemoveDot: string;
begin
  //connect to AD and try exrtact the info /
  lStr := ADsGetObject('WinNT://10.120.200.16/'+edtPRN.Text, IADsUser, usr); // edtPRN.Text >> sAMAccountName
  if Succeeded(lStr) then
  begin
    Usr.GetInfo;
    EmpFullName := Usr.FullName;
    RemoveDot := StringReplace(EmpFullName, '.', '',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    xStrg := Usr.FullName;
    edtLastName.Text := GetLastWord(xStrg);
    xStrg := StringReplace(RemoveDot, edtLastName.Text, '',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    EdtMidName.Text := GetLastWord(xStrg);
    xStrg := StringReplace(RemoveDot, EdtMidName.Text, '',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    xStrg := StringReplace(xStrg, edtLastName.Text, '',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    edtFirstName.Text := GetLastWord(xStrg);
    edtEmail.Text := Usr.EmailAddress;  // <<<<< this is the error 
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The email address attribute is not available using WinNT:// provider, you need to use LDAP:// provider. The name of the attribute is 'mail' not 'emailaddress'. Here is a link to ASDI and Delphi. [ASDI examples](http://www.agnisoft.com/white_papers/active_directory.asp).